# Apostrophe not being recognized

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a row `let's` in my table and now I would like to search that row but I am getting no result. I am able to search other rows but if it contains apostrophe I get no result.

```
 $q = $_GET['term'];

 SELECT * FROM table where title LIKE '%$q%'
```

why it is not showing me that specific row? I have disabled magic_quotes in php.ini

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection). That will also solve your problem. In your case, you need to escape LIKE wildcards `%` and `_`, too, using `addcslashes` (no, not `addslashes`).

Comment: Okay I actually always use mysqli prepared statements but the pagination class I am using now uses pdo.

Comment: Check to see how apostrophes are stored in the database. Sometimes they are stored as "&apos;" or "#39" or something like that. You can convert user input to the appropriate match to fix your search. It has to do with character sets which is a long discussion.

Comment: This is *not* a prepared statement/parameterized query.

Comment: @ChrisWesson They *shouldn't* be stored as HTML entities, that's for outputting content in an HTML context.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I know this is not a prepared statements, the pagination has a class where it binds the parameters or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when `$_GET['term']` contains an apostrophe, e.g. when it contains `let's`? Let's see:

```
SELECT * FROM table where title LIKE '%let's%'
```

You see the apostrophe mismatch? There's your problem.

You need a prepared statement for this. When using PDO, it would read something like

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table where title LIKE ?');
$q = '%' . addcslashes($_GET['term'], '%_') . '%';
$stmt->execute(array($q));
```

When using MySQLi, this would read as follows:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table where title LIKE ?');
$q = '%' . addcslashes($_GET['term'], '%_') . '%';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $q);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note that I also escape `%` and `_`, because they will be treated as wildcards in this context.

Comment: I see a lot of people recommending PDO, buts wrong with improved version of mysql.. i.e mysqli.

Comment: @Vinothbabu PDO has better abstraction possibilities. And if you want to switch from DBMS, you still can use PDO. But I'll provide an answer with MySQLi, too.

Comment: I agree with switching database part, but that migration does not happen too often with many application. I have seen many application changing their application stack than migrating db. I think the best solution would be to choose an ORM like php-activerecord or go with some good frameworks like laravel, but yes its out of scope to the question here... upvoted from my side for this elegant answer.